# Shopify App causing return code 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have this piece of code which is triggered when a new order is created in my Shopify store:

```
class CustomwebhooksController < ShopifyApp::WebhooksController 
  #the line below is to avoid the CSR error
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  include ShopifyApp::WebhookVerification

  # This method is triggered when the user completes the checkout process
  # Gets the order number and see the message "Your order is confirmed" 
  # I should use this as the trigger to update the other SKU for the DT solution:
  def orders_create
    request.body.rewind
    data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

    #redirect_to controller: "home", action: "update_stock", status: :found

    @MyHomeController = HomeController.new
    @MyHomeController.update_stock

    #do not remove line below
    head :ok

  end

end
```

This is the code in my home controller:

```
class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
  def update_stock
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:title => 'DT382'})
    @products.each do |product|
      puts(product.id)
    end  
  end      
end
```

Somehow the call to `@MyHomeController.update_stock` generates a 302 as shown below:

Rendered inline template (0.4ms)
  Completed 302 Found in 689ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You should format/indent the code part for better readability.

Comment: "The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection.

An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the location header field. The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field. The HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) initially defined this code, and gives it the description phrase "Moved Temporarily".

Comment: Look [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/problem-with-embedded-sdk-not-loading-the-iframe-275604)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to challenge your design for a minute.

Firstly, if you're going to redirect to a different controller/action, why aren't you using `redirect_to update_stock_path` where the path is specified in your routes file?

Secondly, why redirect at all? You're receiving a webhook with some payload and then you need to hit the Shopify API to get product data. To me, this is far more suitable as a background job. Furthermore, designing this as `receive webhook -> schedule background job -> do work in the job` will be more scalable than what you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try to use redirect_to. It seemed to work, but the code in the update_stock method, never gets executed. I'm a newbie on Rails although I have experience with Objective-C. Would you be able to point me to some resources on how Shopify webhooks should be programmed using Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the solution after carefully reading the Shopify API documentation.

class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
  def update_stock
    shop_url = "https://#{ENV['API_KEY']}:#{ENV['API_SECRET']}@myshopifyshop.myshopify.com/admin"
    ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:title => 'DT382'})
    @products.each do |product|
      puts(product.id)
    end
   ShopifyAPI::Base.clear_session
  end
end